# linked list and file Handling

Tags: c++

I have tried very much to write and read linked list in file but couldn't succeed. The file is written to successfully but my program cannot read the  linked list from file.

This is my code:

```
case 2:
    temp = first;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        temp->output(temp);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    break;
case 3:  // for write in file
    fstream file;
    file.open("group.dat", ios::app | ios::out | ios::in | ios::binary);
    {
        temp = first;
        while (temp != NULL)
        {

            file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&temp), sizeof(user));

            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }

    exit(-1);
case 4:  // for Read from file
    fstream file;
    file.open("group.dat", ios::app | ios::out | ios::in | ios::binary);
    file.seekg(0);

    while (!file.eof())
    {
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&temp), sizeof(user));

    }
```

Comment: `file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&temp), sizeof(user));`  What is `temp`?  If it's a pointer, why are writing the address of a pointer to a file?  And why binary file writing?  If whatever you're writing is a non-POD type, that line isn't going to work even if you fix the `temp` issue.

Comment: And it seems you almost can't not mention the very high probability that `while (!file.eof())` [is wrong as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: "user" is name of class and "temp" is node of linkedlist. I also write (temp)      instead of (&temp). it works but writes an extra node with garbage value in file.